# Any way to stop mobs spawning within my walls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I know mobs do not spawn on blocks lit with at least 7 light on it. But are there any mods, preferably already in FTB that makes sure mobs will not spawn in a specific area? I'd like to stay on hard mode while still building all kinda cool but expensive and complicated stuff and i really cant have a creeper sneak up on me when i am busy building within my walls.

I do not really care about mobs spawning outside my walls and walking in since my place is pretty huge.

Comment: Note that simply lighting up the whole area is much simpler, cheaper, and more maintainable. FTB includes NEI, which has a "show spawnable locations" feature toggled with F7, which you can use to ensure complete lighting coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether it is in your mod pack, the best mod for making a certain area absolutely safe from mobs in FTB is a system from "Modular Force Field System". Once you have a field set up around the area you want protected, use the [NPC Defense Upgrade](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/MFFS_Projector_Upgrade_-_NPC_Defence) in your MFFS. This will instantly kill any hostile mob that enters or spawns inside the field.

Running it will be rather expensive in power and resources, though, so you may want to pulse it on and off with a timer.

Comment: Awesome! I am going for that as soon a i have my basic systems going. I quickly read over the stuff but is there a certain range to this? My walls are about 128x128, everything underground will be lit properly so i won't be needing it for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you spend most of your time in your base, you could opt to set the game to Peaceful. Once you go outside your base, simply turn it back to your preferred difficulty.
Of course, when you have a need for a (hostile) mob farm, it will not work when in Peaceful mode. 
Also, some people might consider this cheating.

Comment: That is what i did most of the time but i'd like a option within the gameplay boundaries much better.

Comment: I can imagine you do. Added it for completion mainly.